# CSS file not linking to HTML Page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I know there are many such questions but nothing seems to work.I have a Content Page which is stored in a folder 'Registration' and its CSS file is stored in another folder 'StyleSheets'.I am simply dragging and dropping the CSS link to the head section of the Content page.It still doesnt work.

CSS File :

```
    .unmaintable {
        width: 1000px;
        text-align:left;
        background-color:chocolate;
    }
     .unmaintable1 {
        width:250px;
        text-align:center;
    }
     .unmaintable2 {
         width:250px;
    }
      .unmaintable3 {
          width:250px;
    }
       .unmaintable4 {
        width:250px;
    }
       .imagebuttons {
           width:94px;
           height:70px;
    }
```

Content Page :

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Reg-step1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Registration_Reg_step1" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Title" Runat="Server">
  Step 1
  </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
 <link href="../StyleSheets/ContentPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="unmaintable">
                <tr>
                    <td class="unmaintable1">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="unmaintable2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="unmaintable3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="unmaintable4">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="unmaintable1">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="unmaintable2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="unmaintable3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="unmaintable4">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
    </table>
    </asp:Content>
```

One interesting thing here is I get the wanted result in the design mode (using visual studio 2013) but when i run it(IE11,CHROME,FIREFOX) it doesnt do anything.

Comment: Yes,I am sorry it is 'StyleSheets'.I have edited the question too.

Comment: plus one for ironic CSS class name

Comment: @MrLister - I work around like this all the time.The table shows up pretty good when i put in an empty table wthout any border.I have a masterpage and footer so it is quite easy to see the table

Comment: @RachelGallen - If i had to get my job done,I wouldn't have posted the question at the first place.I am just curious why something as simple as this not working.Ofcourse,  posting the CSS in style tags in every page is my last option.

Comment: I just got an idea, maybe your css file is not working because you are putting it inside a content tag. Put it outside of the content tags. Even putting it on the Masterpage would be better. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `<head>` tag in your html. The format should be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='~/css/My.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head> 
<body>
//some html
</body> 
</html>
```

I believe you may be putting css in wrong place.

Comment: It's an aspx page with a master page, and the OP isn't showing the master page in which we can presume the head is defined.

Comment: Edited for ' ' instead of ""

Comment: By the way, even in the case the link was in the body rather than the head, it would still work. Browsers are (far too) forgiving like that.

Comment: Well as MrLister said, it is an aspx page and has ContentPlaceHolders. The question is how can i make a mistake in linking the CSS file when i actually dragging and dropping the link on the html page.I think this puts the exact-working link in there.doesn't it?

Comment: But best practice is to put css in head of main page I dont see why this is a discussion

Comment: Why cant you put it in the head of your layout page?

Comment: @code - what do you mean my main page? master page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="../StyleSheets/ContentPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Change this to

```
<link href="~/StyleSheets/ContentPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then it should work as desired

Comment: No, it doesnt work.It takes away the entire table now

Comment: Put the full URL in the href and ensure your CSS file is correctly named

Answer (score 0):

Please use:
    `<link href="~/StyleSheets/ContentPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server" />`

meant add runat="server" to make relative path workable

Comment: I just did.That doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see DOCTYPE, html, head, body tags which is kind of concerning but try this instead. The `../` might be denoting the wrong path for your css.

```
<link href='~/css/My.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Comment: Please read other answers too.I have tried the above and it doesn't work.It should go one folder up and the  one folder down to locate the CSS file and since i am dragging and dropping the link onto the page,it should be correct.I am using Visual Studio 2013 which has a masterpage and has all the required tags to load a page.This is however a ContentPage